# Trac and VisualSVN Walkthrough?

Tags: svn, trac, bug-tracking, visualsvn-server

Is there a detailed Trac and VisualSVN Integration Walkthrough?

There is a plugin that was released for http://www.visualsvn.com/server/trac/ - but it seems that there are lots of issues.

Does anyone know of a walkthrough?

Comment: Is this a serverfault question?

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers – regardless of platform or language" - don't think so ?

Answer (score 2):

VisualSVN Team just updated Trac plugin and instruction for recently released VisualSVN Server 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Found a guide - pretty sure it works :)

http://wintermuteblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/trac-subversion-installation-on-windows.html